# Windows equivalent of Linux fallocate cmdline tool

Tags: windows, command-line, ntfs

Is there a (free) Windows commandline program to allocate (that is, reserve) arbitrary space in a NTFS filesystem to an arbitrary filename without actually writing to that space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually want to use linux-style `dd of=name_of_file seek=length_of_file bs=1 count=0`, which as far as I can tell should work the same on Windows as on any other POSIX-ish operating system, and should be available through e.g. msys2, or as [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd), try:

```
fsutil file createnew name_of_file size_of_file
```

I *think* should work. Don't have a Windows PC at the moment to test.

Comment: While the `dd` thing does not work on Linux the same as `fallocate` does (`dd` creates a sparse file with zero `du` usage), it does work on Windows (CygWin): It is quick (does not actually write), reduces free filesystem space  and creates a `du` usage as intended. This is what I prefer over the `fsutil` command because it accepts human readable sizes like `1G` which `fsutil` rejects.